# Compare map key with a list of strings

Tags: java, dictionary, comparison

can map be compare with arraylist of string in java

```
private Map<String, String> checkInScopeLobs(Map<String, String> allLobsChkBx)
    {
        Map<String, String> inScopeLobs = new HashMap<String, String>();; 
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : allLobsChkBx.entrySet())
        {
          if(entry.getKey().contains("1") || entry.getKey().contains("2") || entry.getKey().contains("3")){
              inScopeLobs.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
          }
        }
        return inScopeLobs;
    }
```

is this a correct way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `keySet()`. This method returns a `Set` of keys (for more info, [Docs from Oracle about Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)). This means less overhead than iterating over your whole map. In the following case you'll only request values of **matching** keys.

There are some other faults like a double semicolon and since JDK7 you don't have to define your map when initializing.

```
private Map<String, String> checkInScopeLobs(Map<String, String> allLobsChkBx) {
    Map<String, String> inScopeLobs = new HashMap();
    List<String> keys = Arrays.asList( { "1", "2", "3" } );
    for(String key : allLobsChkBx.keySet()) {
        if(keys.contains(key)) {
            inScopeLobs.put(key, allLobsChkBx.get(key));
        }
    }
    return inScopeLobs;
}
```

Why aren't you using an `Integer` instead of a `String`, since you're only storing numbers.

Comment: Double semi colum is a Typo mistake and i should have used Equal since i need to compare exactly 1,2,3 .

Comment: @user2247521 Changed my answer accordingly, just wondering why you're not using `Integer` as key?

Comment: retuning map value is used to populate a checkBok which contains first element as all , 1 ,2,3 .That is y i have used string instead of integer .

Comment: Ok, though a better implementation would be to store this as an `Integer` and let your class that's handling the UI convert this to a `String` for displayingpurposes. It depends on your further use of this `Map` too ofcourse. Anyway, since you've not accepted an answer so far, is there any part of your question you don't consider answered?

Answer (score 0):

Since key is String you can use matches method from String class

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : allLobsChkBx.entrySet())
    {
      if(entry.getKey().matches(".*[123].*")){
          inScopeLobs.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are no such methods, but you can try this approach:

```
Map<String, String> allLobsChkBx = new HashMap<String, String>(4);
allLobsChkBx.put("1", "A");
allLobsChkBx.put("2", "B");
allLobsChkBx.put("3", "C");
allLobsChkBx.put("4", "D");
allLobsChkBx.put("5", "E");

System.out.println("Before retain: " + allLobsChkBx);
List<String> keysToRetain = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "1", "2", "3" });
allLobsChkBx.keySet().retainAll(keysToRetain);
System.out.println("After retain: " + allLobsChkBx);
```

It will produce following output:

```
Before retain: {3=C, 2=B, 1=A, 5=E, 4=D}
After retain: {3=C, 2=B, 1=A}
```

Comment: This won't work Eugene. OP is using `contains()` not `matches()`. The key could be `"abc1"` too, which matches OPs condition but not yours.