# Compare hash map key with the string

Tags: java

I want to compare the string with the key from the hashmap. I tried to use steps mentioned here [Compare map key with a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413143/compare-map-key-with-a-list-of-strings) but didn't work for me.

The hashmap contains many entries and want to compare the string which I am passing. If the key matches the string it should stop there and print the value of matched string.
Below is my code :

```
HashMap<String, MyBO> myObjs = MyData.getMyData();
Set<String> keys = myObjs.keySet();
String  id = "ABC";
for(String code: keys) {
    MyBO bo  = myObjs.get(code);
    if(keys.contains(itemId)) {
        System.out.println("Matched key = " + id);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Key not matched with ID");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I am completely misunderstanding the question, you can just do `if (myObjs.containsKey(itemId))`

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do here. Which "the key", and what are you wanting to compare it to? Why aren't you using `containsKey`?

Comment: Your question is very vague. You mention `HashMap` in your title, and don't use it properly in your code, but need to check something in it?! Its causing people to interpret it differently and post what might not be the answer you're expecting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you

```
    HashMap<String, MyBO> myObjs = MyData.getMyData();
    String  id = "ABC";
    if(myObjs.containsKey(id)){
        System.out.println("Matched key = " + id);
    } else{
        System.out.println("Key not matched with ID");
    }
```

For example consider following example

```
    HashMap<String, String> myObjs =new HashMap<>();
    myObjs.put("ABC","a");
    myObjs.put("AC","a");
    String  id = "ABC";
    if(myObjs.containsKey(id)){
        System.out.println("Matched key = " + id);
    } else{
        System.out.println("Key not matched with ID");
    }
```

Out put.

```
    Matched key = ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and resemble it with your code requirement it w ill work for you

```
for (String key:keys){
            String value = mapOfStrings.get(key);
            //here it must uderstand, that the inputText contains "java" that equals to
            //the key="java" and put in outputText the correspondent value
            if (inputText.contains(key))
            {
               outputText = value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for, note the differences with your code:

```
HashMap<String, MyBO> myObjs = MyData.getMyData();
Set<String> keys = myObjs.keySet();
String  id = "ABC";
for(String code: keys) {
    if(code.equals(id) { /* this compares the string of the key to "ABC" */
        System.out.println("Matched key = " + id);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Key not matched with ID");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, though, you can do:

```
HashMap<String, MyBO> myObjs = MyData.getMyData();
Set<String> keys = myObjs.keySet();
if(keys.contains("ABC") { /* this checks the set for the value "ABC" */
    System.out.println("Matched key = ABC");
 } else {
    System.out.println("Key not matched with ID");
 }
}
```

Comment: No explanation? Just "note the differences?"

Comment: Also, where is the map being used? I really doubt if the OP had that for nothing!

Comment: The OP doesn't use it himself, and it's an arbitrary object type. How could he know how to use it?

Comment: The comment notes the difference and explains why, and the map isn't being used in the for block that it's declared so it's unnecessary.

Comment: *MyBO bo  = myObjs.get(code);* - OP does use it. And also, the question has `HashMap` in it. What about that?!

Comment: The variable `bo` is not used in the scope that it's declared in, so OP does not use it. `HashMap` is used as the type of the variable `myObjs` which is used in the following line to get the key set and store it as `keys`.

Comment: @RickHanlonII - The question is pretty vague. We can't jump onto any conclusions here. I just hope what you assumed about the `HashMap` turns out to be true!

Comment: I don't understand the confusion. The title seems clear enough and the first sentence states "I want to compare the string with the key from the hashmap", which seems straightforward to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
HashMap<String, String> dataArr = new HashMap<>();
        dataArr.put("Key 1", "First String");
        String keyValueStr = dataArr.keySet().toString();
        String matchValueStr = "Key 1";
        //System.out.println(keyValueStr);
        if(keyValueStr.equals("["+matchValueStr+"]"))
            System.out.println("Match Found");
        else
            System.out.println("No Match Found");
```